# command not found in zsh when it is there

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I just installed the android SDK and was trying to run the emulator when this happened:

```
:: ~ » echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/neeraj/code/android/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/neeraj/code/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
:: ~ » whereis emulator
emulator: /home/neeraj/code/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator
:: ~ » emulator
zsh: command not found: emulator
```

`emulator` seems to be in one of the $PATH directories, but zsh still says that it wasn't found. What could be the cause?

Comment: What happens when you call `/home/neeraj/code/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator` ?

Comment: Instead of `whereis` try the *zsh-builtin* `whence`: `whence -v emulator`. It is possible that you have an alias or function with the name `emulator`, both of which would have precedence before external commands (from `$PATH`) and both of which cannot be found with `whereis`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was that `emulator` was a 32-bit ELF binary, and I didn't have the 32-bit runtime libraries installed. I installed the packages `libc6:i386`, `zlib1g:i386`, `libstdc++6:i386` and `lib32z1` as suggested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13409), and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `rehash` command, it helps in cases when some new software is installed. You can also try to run another shell instance (by executing `zsh` or logging out and in), this should also help.

Please also check file permissions to make sure you can read and execute that file.

Comment: neither of these things work. funny thing is, even `cd`ing into the directory and doing `./emulator` results in a `zsh: no such file or directory: ./emulator
`

Comment: @NeerajAdhikari please also check file permissions, maybe you do not have permissions to read or execute?

Comment: I checked the permissions, and both the read and write permissions were there. The problem was that I didn't have the 32-bit runtime libraries to run the 32-bit binary.

Comment: Ahh, I see. The error message was completely misleading.